# Preserving .data() values when appending newly created element to parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, append

I have a piece of jQuery code running in a popup that parses a JSON response from an AJAX request. As part of this, it dynamically creates a series of `<tr>` elements - and their content including anchor elements that have data attributes assigned to them using the `.data()` function -  to update a table in the parent window.

This code works as expected. The rows are created with the correct content, and then added to the table in the main window. There's just one small problem - the data attached to the anchor elements disappears.

The JSON response looks like this (the relevant part is the `locationList` array):

```
{
  "locationList": [{
    "name": "All locations",
    "locid": "-1",
    "countryid": "-1",
    "imtid": "-1"
  }],
  "countries": [
    {
      "value": "-1",
      "text": "All"
    },
    {
      "value": "258",
      "text": "Ireland"
    },
    {
      "value": "246",
      "text": "Sub SA"
    },
    {
      "value": "261",
      "text": "United Kingdom"
    }
  ],
  "locations": [{
    "value": "-1",
    "text": "All"
  }]
}
```

And the Javascript looks like this:

```
var $locations = opener.$('#document-content-locations');
$locations.empty();
for(var i = 0; i < data.locationList.length; i++) {
    var location = data.locationList[i];
    var rowClass = (i % 2 == 0) ? "odd" : "even";
    var row = $('<tr/>').addClass(rowClass);
    row.append($('<td/>').text(location.name));
    var link = $('<a/>').attr('href', '#').data({locid: location.locid, countryid: location.countryid, imtid: location.imtid}).text('remove').addClass('removelocation');
    console.log(link.data());
    row.append($('<td/>').append(link));
    console.log(row.find('a').data());
    $locations.append(row);
    console.log($locations.find('a').data());
}
```

The `console.log` calls are in there to monitor the elements `data` through the various stages. Console output:

```
Object { locid="-1", countryid="-1", imtid="-1"}
Object { locid="-1", countryid="-1", imtid="-1"}
Object {}
```

I **think** what's happening is that the call to `.append()` is, rather than simply appending the element to the table in the main window, cloning the element (minus data and event information) and then adding it to the table in the main window. I tried explicitly cloning the element (passing true to preserve data and events), then appending that element, but the problem persists.

I can resolve the issue by using HTML5 `data-*` attributes in the HTML for the anchor, rather than using the `.data()` function. That's fine for now, since there's only a few, but it's not as easily scalable.

So, I have a few questions:

1. Is my thought/assumption likely to be correct? Is calling
   `.append()` with a newly created element from a popup to add to an
   element in the parent window likely to clone the element (even though there seems to be no reason to do so)?
2. Is there a way - other than going in and modifying the jQuery source code - to tell
   `.append()` (and similar functions) to preserve data and event
   information for any clones it creates as part of execution (I don't think it does this by default)?
3. Am I doing something inherently wrong in the above code that's causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me awhile (about a year - I forgot to come back and answer this when I first figured it out) to realise what was happening here and causing the problem I was having. I didn't really have any understanding of how data was stored against DOM nodes when I asked the question, but I have a better (if not totally complete) idea of what's occurring internally now when calling `.data()` to set and get values.

For DOM nodes jQuery has a global cache which it uses to store all of the data. Each node is then assigned a unique ID that acts as a key to later retrieve the data for that specific node from the cache.

That's all relatively straightforward, so why doesn't it work between browser windows? The answer is (now) quite obvious: each separate window has its own global cache, and the unique ID generated when setting the data in the child (popup) window doesn't match an entry in the global cache for the parent window (if it even gets transferred at all).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like .append() sometimes moves, and sometimes clones.

http://welcome.totheinter.net/2009/03/19/the-undocumented-life-of-jquerys-append/

I've seen the same thing using .append(). In my case, I programmatically create anchors and bind event handlers to them. Then I .append() the anchor objects elsewhere in the DOM, and they lose their event handlers.

Comment: I'm aware that it clones when calling `.append()` on a jQuery object containing more than one element, but in my case it **should** only contain one element (since I'm using an ID selector) and therefore simply move the element.

Comment: Ah, I guess I hadn't read your question clearly enough. Maybe .append() will only clone across browser windows. As a compromise, you could serialized your data object: **link.attr('data-json', JSON.stringify(data))** , and deserialize it when you want to consume it later on: **JSON.parse(link.attr('data-json'))**